# How can I convert from a Route to a URL inside a Model?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

We have a system for building forms. Each prototype of a form element is its own class, as a model in ZF2's MVC.  The classes for a tree structure, and by running through the structure each adds its own HTML to the total outcome.

I realize this breaks MVC, but so far this is a self contained system and is working well.  One problem though is that we want to be able to convert from a Route to a URL like we can in other controllers, given a route name and parameters.

The only option I've found so far is to restructure this code to conform to MVC, and push all the html through the view renderer.  Does anyone know of some alternatives that would allow us to convert a Route to a URL outside of the controllers or models?

---

I'll try to explain the structure without throwing a mountain of code in here.

```
abstract class Element
{
    /**
     * Each concrete element must create its own html
     */
    abstract public function processHtml();

    public function addChild(Element $element)
    {
    }
}
```

Some Elements can hold other Elements. So it builds a tree structure from a root Element.  Then calling processHtml() on the root starts a recursion into the tree.

```
public function processHtml()
{
    $html = '<div>';

    foreach($this->children as $element)
    {
        $html .= $element->processHtml();
    }

    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: The router can return a path for a given route name, so it sounds like you need to pass this in as a depdency. It's quite hard to know how to apply this to your situation without more info / code though.

Comment: @TimFountain updated with some code snippets to explain how its structured.

Comment: Do your forms extend `Element`, or are the elements added to forms in some other way?

Comment: Yes our forms extend `Element`.  Our code that saves, loads, and creates forms always use `Form` objects as a root.

Comment: I think I found an answer, trying it out now.  From the `Url` View Helper `return $this->router->assemble($params, $options);`.  Traced the calls back to this `->setRouter($serviceManager->get('Router'));`  Going to try passing the `ServiceManager` into `processHtml()` and see if I can use the router as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Version: `$router = $serviceLocator->get('Router');`

```
public function processHtml(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $router = $serviceLocator->get('Router');
    $url = $router->assemble($this->Params, array('name' => $this->Route));

    $html = "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>{$this->Label}</a>";
    return $html;
}
```

---

How I found it, in case it helps anyone:

In **Zend\View\Helper\Url::__invoke**
`return $this->router->assemble($params, $options);`

Still in the Url Helper:

```
public function setRouter(RouteStackInterface $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
    return $this;
}
```

**RouteStackInterface** extends **RouteInterface**

So, I went digging through the **Zend\Mvc\Application** and found `->setRouter($serviceManager->get('Router'));` in **Application::bootstrap()**